# Dual monitor issue: The primary monitor is an iMac, the secondary monitor screen shows images in green only

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dvi, imac

I have an iMac with a second monitor (VA2431w) connected to it. The monitor was working fine, however today when it is turned on the screen appears to be green. The mouse and windows can move from one screen to the other without incident, however when items are viewed on the second monitor they appear green. The cable (DVI) that is connected to the monitor appears to be working fine and is firmly connected to the iMac. Does anyone know what could be the reason for this? I will try to connect the monitor to another computer soon to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Any of the DVI connector pins out of place?

Comment: Not that I can tell, they all look like they are there okay, but I will take another look.  Thanks

Comment: Same computer/different screen would be just as useful as same screen/different computer.

Comment: Yeah I plan on doing that too, my boss is currently using the computer, but I plan to try that as well in about an hour.  Thanks

Comment: You were right Daniel, could you post the pin suggestion as an answer so that I could give you credit?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely (heh) your cable: Check the pins at the connectors if they're bent, or some are missing.

Comment: DVI carries each color channel on a separate pin, so if the entire screen is hued a single shade it's almost always the connector.  (Generally you see green or pink.)

Answer (score 0):

**I had the exact same issue.**  I was using an LG flat panel/flat screen monitor (or TV, rather) as my external monitor. The TV was working fine and even the menu screen popped up in full, regular color.  It was just the picture of my iMac desktop in the background that was *green*.

All i did was simply use a paperclip to reset the TV (not the iMac) in the back of the TV. Simple as that. The TV turned off and then when I turned it back on it was fine.